# Fill a form ng-click Angular js issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am developing an application with angular js, I have a table in each row there is an edit button and above the table there is a form, what I need to do is that when user clicks on a specific row then form will be filled with data of that row

Here is my code of form

```
   <form role="form" ng-controller="userController" >

   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentUser.name"/>
      <label>Description</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentUser.Description"/>
   </div>
```

Here is the code of table:

```
   <table class="table" id="user-table" >

        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
          <td>
              {{ user.id }}
          </td>            
          <td>
              {{ user.name }}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{ user.Description }}
          </td>
          <td>
              <a ng-click="setCurrentUser(user.id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
          </td>                
       </tr>           

   </table>
```

In the javascript file in the userController I have the following code

```
     $scope.setCurrentUser= function( id ){         

         $scope.currentUser = $scope.users[id];
          console.log($scope.currentUser);

       }
```

My question is this : Although when I click on the rows the setCurrentUser is run and the object currentUser is printed properly in the console, why the form is not get filled witht the data of $scope.currentUSer
where am I making mistake, or should I just take another approach to handle it?

Comment: Could you set up a demo on jsfiddle.com?

Comment: You are mixing up id and index, passing the user id to get data and are getting that by index

Comment: @HarishR as I mentioned there is no problem  in getting data that console.log prints out exactly what it is supposed to print (btw in this case id and indexes are the same) thanks for your time

Comment: Can Anyone please help me with my doubt : http://stackoverflow.com/q/38546218/6630008

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you could use here. 
**First**, you can set a hole `user` object from table to `currentUser` object:

```
$scope.setCurrentUser= function(user){         
  $scope.currentUser = user;
}
```

**Second**, you can push `$index` from `ng-repeat` into `setCurrentUser($index)` and find user by this index.

```
<table class="table" id="user-table" >

    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
          {{ user.id }}
      </td>            
      <td>
          {{ user.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{ user.Description }}
      </td>
      <td>
          <a ng-click="setCurrentUser($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
      </td>                
   </tr>           
</table>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.setCurrentUser= function(index){         
  $scope.currentUser = $scope.users[index];
}
```

Chek `$index` property in [ngRepeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)